# counting how many elements of a specific column of an array starts with letters "ZS"

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

i have a multidimensional dynamic array with 11 columns.
how do i count how many elements in column 4 starts with "ZS" (there can be items with no value, other with "ZC973279473" and others with "ZS5367276". i care only about the one like "ZS773746".)
i tried with

```
XNSites = Application.Count(Application.Match(Left(myarray.Columns(4), 2), "ZS", 0))
```

and

```
XNSites = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Left(myarray.columns(4), 2), "=" & "ZS")
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data seems to be alphanumeric, with just the first two chars as letters, you could prevent a loop using a 1D-array extract from a 2D-array when you apply `FILTER`:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, arr3 As Variant
Dim lr As Long

With Sheet1 'Change to your own sheets CodeName

    'Fill dynamic 2D-array for testing (not sure how you get your array)
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = .Range("A1:K" & lr).Value2

    'Get you 1D-array for the 4th column
    With Application
        arr2 = .Transpose(.Index(arr1, 0, 4))
    End With

    'Count elements starting with ZS
    arr3 = Filter(arr2, "ZS")
    Debug.Print UBound(arr3) + 1

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask you how to do the same thing but in the case i want to count all those elements that starts with "ZS in Column 4 and "1" in column 11? is that possible?

Comment: With some tweaks it is. But you'll have to first create a dictionary

Comment: is it possible to do the same thing that i had to do but mantain the 11 columns? therefore not extracting a one dimension array but a multidimensional one?

Comment: There is none that I'm aware of, unless you get your data of a sheet and work through AutoFilter. Otherwise I'm afraid you have to do a loop. Which isn't slow when done through memory though.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple iteration will help you:

```
Dim Count As Long
Dim ColCell As Range
For Each ColCell In myarray.Columns(11).Cells
    If Left(ColCell.Value, 2) = "ZS" Then
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
Next ColCell
Debug.Print "Total: " & Count
```

Comment: Are you sure it should work? it gives me "invalid qualifier error on the array

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code( I believe all you care about values in column 4). This code will
copy the entire rows which have ZS values at the beginning in column 4 and paste it on sheet2

If data is not on sheet1,please change the sheetname :)

```
Sub you()

lfr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    
For x = 2 To lfr    
If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(x,4).Value Like "ZS*" Then    
Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(x).Copy    

Worksheets("sheet2").Activate    
bfr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    
Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(bfr + 1, 1).Select    
ActiveSheet.Paste    


End If    
Next    
Application.CutCopyMode = False     
Worksheets("sheet1").Activate     
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select     

End Sub
```

If you want just the count try below(You please change rahge from gi to wherever you want the count number) :-

```
 Sub you()

    lfr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To lfr
    KLA = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(x, 4).Value Like "ZS")

    Range("g1") = KLA



    Next

    End Sub
```